# How to query for multiple custom metas using Content Service microservice in Web 8.5?

Tags: web8.5, content-service

I need to fetch multiple custom metas using Content Service microservice in Web 8.5, found that this is the issue in odata in earlier versions as described in the below URL
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/odata-how-to-query-multiple-custom-metas

Can this be achieved using the Content Service, or is it still the issue?

Comment: I think it's possible, are you looking for CIL APIs for custom meta query? Here is the list of Content Service API documentation https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-2F41CB23-912F-4149-9C16-34AB00E67E4E

Comment: @Velmurugan, using /CustomMetas, we will be able to search for only 1 field, not multiple fields, do you have any example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query;

namespace SDL.CIL.Test
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Query query = new Query();

            List criteria = new List
            {
                new ItemSchemaCriteria(340),
                new PublicationCriteria(8),
                new ItemTemplateCriteria(350)
            };

            query.Criteria = CriteriaFactory.And(criteria.ToArray());

            List artickecategoryQuery = new List();
            CustomMetaValueCriteria nameCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("field-name1"), "value", Criteria.Equal);
            artickecategoryQuery.Add(nameCriteria);
            query.Criteria.AddCriteria(CriteriaFactory.Or(artickecategoryQuery.ToArray()));

            CustomMetaValueCriteria authorCriteria = new CustomMetaValueCriteria(new CustomMetaKeyCriteria("field-name2"), "value", Criteria.Equal);
            artickecategoryQuery.Add(authorCriteria);
            query.Criteria.AddCriteria(CriteriaFactory.Or(artickecategoryQuery.ToArray()));

            string[] componentsUris = query.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach(var itemId in componentsUris)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(itemId);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            Log.Info("Finished");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```